# Match two number files to get out of range and within a range

Tags: unix, awk

I have two input files:

```
cat 2OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
111111111   902123124  201605240534270000000070OCS0144 01.0946  0.3729
111111111   902123125  201605222207410000000070OCS8182 00.8980     0.1
111111111   902123126  201605222319190000000015OCS1573 6.3854     6.11
111111111   902123126  201605230752420000000080OCS1223 00.8002     0.0
111111111   902123123  201605231525320000000073OCS1394 01.2194     0.4
111111111   902123123  201605231708080000000570OCS1040 011.1977    6.3
111111111    350       201605240042070000000236OCS4252 3.6344     1.55
111111111    1         201605240114430000000123OCS1154 03.0537    1.89
111111111    3         201605240246070000000009OCS0707 018.6965   18.4
111111111    423       201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881    0.00
111111111    5         201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881    0.00
111111111    470       201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059   15.5
111111111    600       201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059   15.5
111111111    400       201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059   15.5
```

Another file

```
cat BlackList_B_Number.dat
902123123   902123125
902123127   902123128
450               600
1                 400
```

I want match to get out of range of numbers and within range in different files. I tried this:

```
awk -v FILE1="FILE1.out" -v FILE2="FILE2.out" 'NR==FNR{for (i=$1; i<=$2; i++) wanted[i] ;next}($2 in wanted){print > FILE1}!($2 in wanted){print > FILE2}' BlackList_B_Number.dat 2OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
```

But i don't get output expected, because `902123124` should be in `FILE1`, not in `FILE2`:

```
cat FILE1.out
111111111   902123123  201605231525320000000073OCS1394 01.2194     0.4
111111111   902123123  201605231708080000000570OCS1040 011.1977    6.3
111111111    350       201605240042070000000236OCS4252 3.6344     1.55
111111111    1         201605240114430000000123OCS1154 03.0537    1.89
111111111    3         201605240246070000000009OCS0707 018.6965   18.4
111111111    5         201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881    0.00
111111111    470       201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059   15.5
111111111    600       201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059   15.5
111111111    400       201605240601120000000015OCS0156 015.8059   15.5

cat FILE2.out
111111111   902123124  201605240534270000000070OCS0144 01.0946  0.3729
111111111   902123125  201605222207410000000070OCS8182 00.8980     0.1
111111111   902123126  201605222319190000000015OCS1573 6.3854     6.11
111111111   902123126  201605230752420000000080OCS1223 00.8002     0.0
111111111         423  201605240530500000000213OCS0130 01.8881    0.00
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce it on `GNU Awk 4.1.4`, I can see `902123124` present   in `FILE1`

Comment: That script **CANNOT** do what you claim it does given those input files. Try running `cat -v` on each file to see if contains any control characters. Try it again using exactly what you've posted and take another look at your real data.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v FILE1="FILE1.out" -v FILE2="FILE2.out" '
     FNR==NR {BLs[++BSize]=$1;BHs[BSize]=$2;next}
     {
     Blacked=0
     for( i=1; i<BSize && ! Blacked; i++) Blacked = ( $2 >= BLs[i] && $2 <= BHs[i])
#print "DEBUG:: " FNR ": Blacked: " Blacked " : " $0
     if ( Blacked ) print > FILE2
      else print > FILE1
     }' BlackList_B_Number.dat 2OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
```

you don't check for value between 2 value in your version but if part of the listed value (you specify *between*, i assume edge are included in the *between*)

Explain:
- load 2 array for limit specification by reading first file (black list), 1 for low and 1 for high
- reading next file (data)
 - compare on each line if number is between each specified limits (stop at first hit if any) and define if blacked or not
- depending Balcked status, printed to file 1 or 2

Comment: Thanks a lot NeronLeVelu !!!. It seems really good, but i can´t get run. I get error:

Comment: >      FNR=NR {BLs[++BSize]=$1;BHs[BSize]=$2;next}
>      {
>      Blacked=0
>      for( i=1; i<BSize && ! Blacked; i++) Blacked = ( $2 >= BLs[i] && $2 <= BHs[i])
>      if Blacked print > FILE2
>       else print FILE1
>      }' BlackList_B_Number.dat 2OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111
 error de sintaxis La línea de origen es 6.
 El contexto del error es
                     if >>>  Blacked <<<  print > FILE2
 awk: La sentencia no se puede analizar correctamente.
 La línea de origen es 6.

Comment: sorry 2 minor error ( FNR=NR -> FNR==NR and a > before second print). Post corrected

Comment: And.. only it would be fantastic... How can i adapt the previous script, to a program.awk. For example:     

awk -f Program.awk  BlackList_B_Number.dat OCS_VOICECALLS_1111_11_111111

Program.awk:
------------
BEGIN{}

{}

FIN {}

Comment: just keept the code between the 2 last `'` without the quote (so starting at `FNR==`) in a file (ex: YourCode.awk)  and call it with same parameter + `-f YourCode.awk` but it's perhaps better to keep it in a batch and calling the batch with argument